# Estou com dificuldade em criar um banco de dados e relacionar 3 tabelas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com dificuldade em criar um banco de dados e relacionar 3 tabelas : que retorne o nome e sobrenome do cliente, seu bairro, e os valores das suas movimentações,a data ordenando as movimentações
para que esse comado sql funcione

```
 SELECT ClienteNome, ClienteSobrenome, ClienteBairro, MovimentoData,MovimentoValor

 FROM Clientes, Contas, Movimentos

 WHERE Clientes.ClienteCodigo=Contas.ClienteCodigo

 AND Contas.ContaNumero=Movimentos.ContaNumero

 ORDER BY MovimentoData desc;
```

Comment: O seu problema é para criar ou acessar as informações inputadas nesse banco, @LucasNicolauRochaSantos?
Porque o seu código só está selecionando dados que já deveriam ser existentes, e não está criando o BD. 
Explique melhor o seu objetivo e o que você já tem, para que possa te ajudar

Comment: @Luan Naufal peço desculpas mas o problema é criar um banco(estou com dificuldade para criar estrutura para aquele select funciona)

Comment: Qual o erro que você está recebendo ao tentar criar, @LucasNicolauRochaSantos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz um comentário para entender melhor seu objetivo.

Mas uma coisa clara é que você está acessando os campos de forma errada:
Você deveria escrever

```
SELECT Cliente.Nome, Cliente.Sobrenome, Cliente.Bairro, Movimentos.Data, Movimentos.Valor
```

Também você chamou o nome errado da Tabela `Movimentos`, e escreveu `Movimento`

Me detalhe melhor o objetivo que atualizo a resposta!

Comment: Luan Naufal obrigado pela sua ajuda ,desculpa por não ser tao claro, pela sua correção de seu select pode altera minha tabela e me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Não se preocupe, @LucasNicolauRochaSantos! Estamos aqui para ajudar. 
Boa sorte

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma, preste atenção no `select` pois os nomes das tabelas no mesmo estavam escritos de forma incorreta.

```
SELECT Clientes.Nome, Clientes.Sobrenome, Clientes.Bairro, Movimentos.Data, Movimentos.Valor
FROM Clientes, Contas, Movimentos
WHERE Clientes.Codigo = Contas.Codigo
AND Contas.Numero = Movimentos.Numero
ORDER BY Movimento.Data desc;
```